# Override value of existing key in hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have a function that recieves a hashTable and i apply it to an already existing hashTable.

What I would like to do is replace or update a key's value in the hashTable when passed to the function. Here is an example of what i mean:

```
void UpdateHashTable(Hashtable ht){      
           userData.Add("myKey",5);
//replace matching keys from old value to the new ht values in argument 
}

void replacement(){
  Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable;
            hashTable.Add("mykey",15);

  UpdateHashTable(hashTable);
}
```

Is there a built in replace function to do this or some way to check matching keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question a bit hard to understand, but assuming I understood correctly:

There isn't a built in copy that does the behaviour you are talking about, but it's very easy to implement.

steps: foreach keyvaluepair, check if the key exists, if it does, insert. otherwise, update existing.

```
void UpdateHashTable(Hashtable ht){
    foreach(var kvp in ht){
        if(userData.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)){
            userData[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }
        else{
            userData.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

example outcome:

ht [ 2 => "A", 3 => "B"]

userData [ 3 => "C", 4 => "D" ]

userData after updateHashTable [ 2=> "A", 3 =>"B", 4=>"D"]

Comment: Thank you,very useful - surprised there is no built in function for it.

Comment: At best, there are Linq functions you can use for Dictionaries that make this process more compact, but these aren't available for Hashtables. Still, if you want to use a Dictionary, it is pretty much the same as Hashtable. The only real difference is Dictionary is a generic type structure, not object based, and isn't thread-safe.